# Sublime vintage key remapping

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

I am using ST3 and am trying to remap this key to shift+k

```
{ "keys": ["$"], "command": "set_motion", "args": {
    "motion": "vi_move_to_hard_eol",
    "motion_args": {"repeat": 1, "extend": true},
    "inclusive": true,
    "clip_to_line": true },
    "context": [{"key": "setting.command_mode"}]
},
```

Also, I tried to have this key remapped to shift+j...but no luck

```
{ "keys": ["^"], "command": "set_motion", "args": {
    "motion": "vi_move_to_first_non_white_space_character",
    "motion_args": {"extend": true },
    "clip_to_line": true },
    "context": [{"key": "setting.command_mode"}]
},
```

Please let me know how I can have it work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the uppercase char:

```js
{ "keys": ["K"], "command": "set_motion", "args": {
    "motion": "vi_move_to_hard_eol",
    "motion_args": {"repeat": 1, "extend": true},
    "inclusive": true,
    "clip_to_line": true },
    "context": [{"key": "setting.command_mode"}]
},
```